# How to group values in a column in Panda and get corresponding value in another column?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a Pandas data frame like below.

```
    X    Y   Z
0  10   101  1
0  12   120  2
0  15   112  3
0  06   115  4
0  07   125  1
0  17   131  2
0  14   121  1
0  11   127  2
0  13   107  3
0  02   180  4
0  19   114  1
```

I want to calculate the average of the values in column X according to the group values in Z.

That is something like

```
      X           Z
(10+7+14+19)/4    1
(12+17+11)/2      2
(15+13)/2         3
(2+6/1)           4
```

What is an optimum way of doing this using Pandas?

It works this way,

```
sample_data = [['X','Y','Z'],[10,101,1],[12,120,2],[15,12 ,3],[6,115,4],[7,125,1],[17,131,2]]

def group_X_based_on_Z(data):
    value_pair = [(row[2], row[0]) for row in data[1:]]
    dictionary_with_groouped_values = {}
    for z, x in value_pair:
        dictionary_with_groouped_values.setdefault(z, []).append(x)
    return dictionary_with_groouped_values


def cal_avg_values(data):
    grouped_dictionary = group_X_based_on_Z(data)
    avg_value_dictionary = {}
    for z, x in grouped_dictionary.items():
        avg_value_dictionary[z] = mean(x)
    return avg_value_dictionary

print(cal_avg_values(sample_data))
```

I want to know whether there is a Pandas specific method for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use the groupby function.

```
df.groupby('Z').agg(x_avg = ('X', 'mean'))
```

edit: forgot a ')'

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
s=df.groupby('Z',as_index=False).X.mean()
   Z          X
0  1  12.500000
1  2  13.333333
2  3  14.000000
3  4   4.000000
```